# Netlify Exit Code 128

Tags: git, netlify

I am trying to build my front end react app on netlify but I am getting the

- 12:57:50 AM: Exit code: 128
- 12:57:50 AM: Command: git
- 12:57:50 AM: Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/lokesh/quantize.git

error. My colorthief modules needs the quantize module and it is publicly available, so I am not understanding where the error is at?

```
"node_modules/quantize": {
      "version": "1.2.0",
      "resolved": "git+ssh://git@github.com/lokesh/quantize.git#f572abd2646b5944852535c8a26fdb958a5d7c4b",
      "license": "MIT"
    },
```

Comment: You've told something (whatever it is that's invoking Git here) that Git should use ssh, not http(s), to access this repository. Git is therefore invoking ssh to gain access to the repository, and ssh is failing to gain access to GitHub. You have the options of using https with no authentication, or using your personal ssh key or a deploy key to access GitHub.